# AngularJS $http.get() takes up to 10-20 seconds in Chrome, works fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs, flask, cors

I'm encountering an odd error with AngularJS / Google Chrome. When I do an $http.get() it takes up to 18 seconds before it actually completes. It seems to keep at "PENDING" for the "OPTIONS" method:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCQKa.png

The server that serves the pages is Mongoose, the one @ localhost:5000 is Flask, who returns the following headers in order for the CORS to work.

```
@mod.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,     Accept')
```

Anyone knows why Chrome is delaying the OPTIONS request? (From the flask server debug console, it seems that the OPTIONS method really only arrives 10-20 seconds after the page has been reloaded). It seems to work fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to have been solved once I disabled the "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" option. Very odd, perhaps I should leave this question open for if someone could give a possible reason for this?

Edit: See comments for the reason!

Comment: Hi Busata we have the same issue and I wonder if you've been able to grasp why this is happening?

Comment: I didn't investigate it any further after disabling the option, I'll try later this week, perhaps it's a Chrome bug?

Comment: I have the same issue, and YES, once I disable the "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" option the problem disappear. Someone has some news how fix this issue?

Comment: It's caused by the Flask development server processing requests serially on a single thread. Chrome's prediction optimization opens multiple connections in parallel, and the Flask server times out waiting for data on some of these connections (even if there's no data being sent). The simplest solution is to use a production web server like Tornado. See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639355/extremely-long-wait-time-when-loading-rest-resource-from-angularjs/25835028#25835028)