# Angular is superslow when fetching data from local server

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs

I have a simple server built using Flask. It returns a list of cars which an application built using angular displays. The issue is that angular is taking much time, and the webservice is local. I'm providing all my files below:

My Python Flask File: The flask cross origin file is [this file](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/)

```
        from flask import Flask
        from cross_origin import crossdomain
        import json
        app = Flask(__name__)

        cars = []

        #defining cars
        class Car:
                def __init__(self,brand,color,plate_number):
                        self.brand = brand
                        self.color = color
                        self.plate_number = plate_number

        #adding cars
        car1 = Car("BMW","black","GJG 5776")
        cars.append(car1)

        car2 = Car("Jaguar","Silver","HGT 7668")
        cars.append(car2)

    @app.after_request
    def call_after_request_callbacks(response):
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept"
    return response

@app.route("/cars", methods=['GET'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def getCars():
        global cars
        current_cars = []
        for car in cars:
                current_car = {}
                current_car["brand"] = car.brand
                current_car["color"] = car.color
                current_car["plate_number"] = car.plate_number
                current_cars.append(current_car)
        return str(json.dumps(current_cars))
```

The **index.html**:

```
tle>Angularity</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .loaded{display: none;}
        .loading{display: block;}
        div#wrapper{width:700px; margin:20px auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <loading></loading>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div><!-- wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl:'partials/cars_tpl.html', controller: 'showCarCtrl'});
    //.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

app.controller('showCarCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope,CarService){
        $rootScope.loading = true;

        CarService.getCars()
            .then(function(data){
                $rootScope.loading = false;
                $scope.cars = data;
            },

            //deferred
            function(data){
                console.log('Car Service failed');
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            });
});
```

**directives.js**
    'use strict';

```
/* Directives */
app.directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading" ng-show="loading"><img src="img/loading.gif"/>Loading...</div>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
              $scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {

              });
        }
      }
  });
```

**services.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Services */
app.factory('CarService', function($http, $q) {
   return {
     getCars: function(){
        var d = $q.defer();
        var config = {
            'url' : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/cars',
            'method' : 'GET',
        };
        $http.get(config.url)
          .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data)
                d.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            d.reject(data);
        });
        return d.promise;
     },
}});
```

~

Comment: Did not read the code in detail, but where is the delay happening? (Chrome network tab?). I had something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208485/angularjs-http-get-takes-up-to-10-20-seconds-in-chrome-works-fine-in-firefox

Comment: The delay is on the get request, when I do the same thing using jquery, it is done in 1 seconds, with angular, its 13 seconds